# Apple In App Purchase - Buying customized content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an application in which I want to offer the ability to pay for answers to questions in digital format. I.e, the user would submit a question, and purchase an answer which I would construct and send back to the app. Is this allowed?

Comment: Consider supporting the [App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) proposal on Area 51.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if purchasing answers to unknown questions directly would be allowed or not, but I'm sure you could simply sell 'credits' that would give x number of requests.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but unfortunately the Developer Agreement states:`2.1   You may not use the In App Purchase API to enable an end-user to set up a pre-paid 
account to be used for subsequent purchases of content, functionality, or services, or otherwise 
create balances or credits that end-users can redeem or use to make purchases at a later time.  `

Comment: I dont see how this is different to games that sell stars that you can later redeem for bonus items.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is allowed. See section 11 of the App Review Guidelines for iOS, [found here, login required](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).